# Динамическое обновление series highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, highcharts

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/)

Делаю динамическое обновление `series []` и `categories []`.

С `categories`, все получилось через `options.xAxis.categories` передавая туда `$data[0] = array();`

Подскажите, как передать шесть результатов в `series`.

В примере это выглядит так:

```
series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
    }]
```

GrafSub400.js

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/grafSub400.php",
            data: {"type": type, "id_dev": id_dev},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                data = eval(response);
                options.xAxis.categories = data[0];
             // options.series.data = data[1]; // ????
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            }
        });
```

grafSub400.php

```
$data[0] = array();
$data[1] = array();
do
{
    $data[0][] = $mynum['zav_num'];

    $sub400_id = $mynum['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SUB_REZ WHERE        sub400_id='$sub400_id' AND sub_rez_name_id='$type'");
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $data[1][] = ????            //$myrow['r1'] .... $myrow['r6']
}
while ($mynum = mysql_fetch_assoc($resnum));

echo  json_encode($data);
```